# Simple angr example not working

Tags: c, angr

I am trying to learn angr from beginning. Due to lack of simple tutorials I programmed my own little executable which angr should solve.

The C code looks as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buffer[20];
    printf("Password\n");
    fgets(buffer,20,stdin);
    if (strcmp(buffer,"super!\n")==0) {
        printf("SUCCESS!\n");
    } else {
        printf("FAIL!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled and opened in binary ninja I see the printfs at following addresses:
[image: BN]
So I created following angr python3 code:

```
import angr
from angr.state_plugins import SimSystemPosix

p = angr.Project('./test')
state = p.factory.entry_state()



sm = p.factory.simulation_manager(state)
sm.explore(find=0x40118c, avoid=0x40119a)

print(sm.found)
```

Running the python code shows following output:

> python3 solve_angr.py 
>   WARNING | 2020-06-08 10:02:29,497 | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | The program is accessing memory or registers with an unspecified value. This could indicate unwanted behavior.
>   WARNING | 2020-06-08 10:02:29,497 | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | angr will cope with this by generating an unconstrained symbolic variable and continuing. You can resolve this by:
>   WARNING | 2020-06-08 10:02:29,497 | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | 1) setting a value to the initial state
>   WARNING | 2020-06-08 10:02:29,497 | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | 2) adding the state option ZERO_FILL_UNCONSTRAINED_{MEMORY,REGISTERS}, to make unknown regions hold null
>   WARNING | 2020-06-08 10:02:29,497 | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | 3) adding the state option SYMBOL_FILL_UNCONSTRAINED_{MEMORY_REGISTERS}, to suppress these messages.
>   WARNING | 2020-06-08 10:02:29,498 | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | Filling memory at 0x7fffffffffefff8 with 72 unconstrained bytes referenced from 0x58d4e0 (strcmp+0x0 in libc.so.6 (0x8d4e0))
>   WARNING | 2020-06-08 10:02:29,499 | angr.state_plugins.symbolic_memory | Filling memory at 0x7fffffffffeff70 with 8 unconstrained bytes referenced from 0x58d4e0 (strcmp+0x0 in libc.so.6 (0x8d4e0))
>   []

The [] indicates that it did not find any solution.

Can anybody tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the issue is related to the way `gets` symbolic procedure implemented in angr. You are asking to read 20 bytes, and as far as I understand, the actual symbolic memory that is allocated is of the size of 20 (19 string characters and a NULL terminator). Later, when you call to `strcmp`, the comparison will always fail, because you compare 20 bytes string to `super!\n` which is shorter. So the compare result will never be 0, and angr's symbolic execution engine will never reach the `printf("SUCCESS!\n");` clause.

If you modify your code to be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buffer[20];
    printf("Password\n");
    fgets(buffer,8,stdin); // <-------------- Adjust size to be same as "super!\n"
    if (strcmp(buffer,"super!\n")==0) {
        printf("SUCCESS!\n");
    } else {
        printf("FAIL!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This way it works fine and reaches `printf("SUCCESS!\n");`

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify the binary but through the static analysis you get the number of bytes you need to provide as a flag, you can construct bit vector

```
flag_chars = [claripy.BVS('flag_%d' % i, 8) for i in range(6)]
flag = claripy.Concat(*flag_chars + [claripy.BVV(b'\n')])
```

and pass that to the `entry_state` since the flag is provided as an input through `stdin` to this binary.

```
p = angr.Project('test')
state = p.factory.entry_state(args=['./test'], stdin=flag)
```

With such setup, `angr` will successfully find the solution.

Additionally, if you would like to extract the flag

```
found = sm.found[0]
flag_str = found.solver.eval_upto(flag, 7, cast_to = bytes)
print(flag_str)
```